# Найти для сравнения готовые продукты

Tags: c#, delphi, auth, криптография, password-hash

Написал программу аутентификации по системе "рукопожатия", теперь ее надо сравнить с другими аналогичными продуктами, но что-то не могу найти. Скажите пожалуйста, пару названий таких приложений пожалуйста

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь - похоже на шифрование с открытым ключом. Я так понимаю метод «рукопожатия» состоит в следующем. Функция парольного преобразования известна только пользователю и системе защиты. При входе подсистема аутентификации генерирует случайную последовательность x, которая передается пользователю. Пользователь вычисляет результат функции y=f(x) и возвращает его в систему. Система сравнивает собственный вычисленный результат с полученным от пользователя. При совпадении указанных результатов подлинность пользователя считается доказанной. [источник](http://sernam.ru/ss_23.php)

Comment: Так и есть) но готовых продуктов для сравнения, найти что-то не могу. Помогите пожалуйста найти

Comment: Разве системы аутентификации, построенные на том что кто-то не знает только алгоритм преобразования не считаются ненадежными? Я к тому что мне интересно: какое практическое применение у такой системы?